# XAxis labels overlaps with XAxis Title

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

XAxis Labels are overlapping with the xAxis Title. Look at [Bargraph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woCj4.png)

Tried to introduce `padding{bottom:50}` but then xAxis Title hides. Look at[Barchart2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWiXs.png)

```
g.append("text")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + (margin.left + ((width - margin.right - margin.left) / 2.0)) + "," + ((height-margin.bottom + parseInt(titleFontSize) + 40 + axisXMargin)) + ")")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", titleFontSize + "px")
            .style("font-family", titleFontName)
            .style("font-weight", function(d) {
                    if (titleFontStyle == "bold") {
                        return "bold";
                    } else {
                        return "normal";
                    }
            })
            .style("font-style", function(d) {
                    if (titleFontStyle == "italic") {
                        return "italic";
                    } else {
                        return "normal";
                    }
            })
            .text(xAxisName);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to position your xAxis title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe setting the width, height and margins would help. Something like this

```
const svg = d3.select('.canvas')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 600)
    .attr('height', 600);

// create margins and dimensions
const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100 };
const graphWidth = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
const graphHeight = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const graph = svg.append('g')
    .attr('width', graphWidth)
    .attr('height', graphHeight)
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
```

Comment: I have already set the width, margins, and heights as you can see:
`var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 90,
            left: 150
        },
        width = 1200,
        height = 800;
     var g = svg
        .attr("width", +width)
        .attr("height", +height)
        .append("g")`

Comment: and playing with those margins and heights doesn't do anything  in regarding to the Xaxis title? What is the size of your canvas?

Comment: And did you transform and translate the Xaxis title?

Comment: Yeah, you can see the above code I have attached to the question as well as comment. Playing with margin leads to hiding the title.